# Can I safely use Ordering::Relaxed in single-threaded contexts?

Tags: rust, atomic

I need `(Ref)UnwindSafe`ty, and `Cell<bool>` doesn't provide it, so I'm using `AtomicBool` instead.

Is it guaranteed that, in a single-threaded context, updates to one `Rc<AtomicBool>` using `Relaxed` (store) ordering are immediately visible on other `Rc<AtomicBool>`s using `Relaxed` (load) ordering? (The `Rc`s point to the same `AtomicBool`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ordering` is about visibility guarantees in the presence of other threads. Memory accesses are always immediately visible within the current thread (barring noalias violations). So even the weakest ordering requirements (`Relaxed`) are still at least as strong as normal accesses such as those provided by `Cell`.

Comment: I find the ordering stuff complicated; do you have any citations or resources to back up this claim / to provide further reading?

Comment: @Shepmaster rust uses llvm which in turn mostly bases its memory model on C/C++, so reading the C++ docs on atomics might be helpful.